# Tinybrowser is not working in Chrome 17.x and FF 10.x

Tags: php, flash, upload

While working on a very old codebase I've got recently I came across an issue with Tinybrowser 1.41 which is used in it. I figured out the upload is broken in FF and Chrome but works in IE8 and IE9.

After I did some research I figured out that 1.41 is a very old version and that 1.42 is very likely not much better and that the way to get it sucks (see http://www.lunarvis.com/products/tinymcefilebrowserwithupload.php#download).

I think the cause of the problem is the flash uploader but I have no idea how to get this to work with modern browsers. I'm looking for a solution to this issue, guess its a common one with this tool and I hope somebody knows the answer to it.

If you know a good *modern* alternative that has equal features I would appreciate this also as a valid and good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue and ended up figuring out that if I was in SSL then Chrome & FireFox wouldn't work, but if I was not in SSL mode then they worked perfectly.

I don't have a fix for this work around though, so if you're forced to be in SSL mode you're out of luck.